# e-mail properties lost when copied to Outlook Public Folders

Tags: vba, outlook

My VBA application moves/copies selected, locally stored, e-mails to a designated Public Folder to which I have a full access.

The problem is that the To and From properties get messed up after the email is moved/copied. That is:

original From: GuyA

original To: Me

after-move From: Me

after-move To: the name of the public folder

I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to make any difference on the e-mails in the public folder

```
For Each email In a1Bucket.items
    sender = email.SentOnBehalfOfName
    receiver = email.ReceivedOnBehalfOfName
    email.Move largeBucket
    email.SentOnBehalfOfName = sender
    email.To = receiver
Next
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you add this one line `email.Save` before "next"

Comment: Hmm... "The opration cannot be performed because the object has been deleted." How do I keep a reference to that email object?

Comment: Ok I have deleted my post. What was the error that you got when you tried the code?

Comment: "The opration cannot be performed because the object has been deleted." on the .save line

Comment: Ok wait. Let me do a quick test with a local folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (**TESTED ON LOCAL FOLDER**)

```
For Each Email In a1Bucket.items
    sender = Email.SentOnBehalfOfName
    receiver = Email.ReceivedOnBehalfOfName
    Set currentMailItem = Email.Move (largeBucket)
    currentMailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = sender
    currentMailItem.To = receiver
    currentMailItem.Save
Next
```

Comment: @Krzysiek: Try the updated code now. Also add `Dim currentMailItem as Object` at the top.

Comment: Kind of working! The .To field has changed, but not the SentOnBehalfOfName. It still lists my name...

Comment: Good News :) Let me experiment more :)

Comment: Hmmm, it works for me in local folders. Can you debug it and see what is the value of `sender`? Add `Debug.Print currentMailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` after the save command. What do you get?

Comment: It shows the correct sender... but when I go to the public folder and open the e-mail, the sender stays as me. No clue what's up :(

Comment: I think the public folder was hunted or something.. I created a new, parallel public folder "largeBucket2" and now every e-mail copied into it preserves To and From field. Wow...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim newEMail As Outlook.MailItem    
For Each email In a1Bucket.items
    sender = email.SentOnBehalfOfName
    receiver = email.ReceivedOnBehalfOfName
    Set newEMail = objmail.Move(largeBucket)
    'email.Move largeBucket
    newEMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = sender
    newEMail.To = receiver
Next
```

You may also need to save it after this. You keep a reference to the object - after being moved - with the above code.

The following:

```
email.SentOnBehalfOfName = sender
email.To = receiver
```

only modifies the original email (and **not** the after moved email). It is not associated with the new email/mail object.